# GoogleMap v2 API 10 error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have the following error on API 10:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ter.androidapp/com.ter.androidapp.activities.RootActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #106: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #106: Error inflating class fragment
```

This is where I load map:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (mMapViewContainer == null) {
        here it crash -> mMapViewContainer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_geoloc_map, null);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview_geolo);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    FaceBookShareManager.getInstance().initialize(getString(R.string.facebookId));

    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        setupTabBarColors(0);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.leftPanelContainer, new StationsSearchFragment(), Constants.TAG_STATION_FRAGMENT).commit();
    }

    if (getIntent() != null && Constants.WIDGET_STATION_CLICK.equals(getIntent().getAction()) && getIntent().getData() != null) {
        displayStationFromWidget(Integer.valueOf(getIntent().getData().getSchemeSpecificPart()));
    }

    setTrackFromNotif();

    checkForTrainFromWidget(getIntent());
    if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        onNewIntent(getIntent());
    }
}
```

This is from fragment_geoloc_map.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:background="@color/transparent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_trainNum"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textSize="@dimen/xxLargeText"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/geolocInfoContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_rechercher_red"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="14dp"
            android:paddingTop="14dp"
            android:text="@string/selectStation"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/xxxLargeText"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_choose_radius"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_refresh_map"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_refresh_map"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_radius"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/radius"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
            android:textSize="@dimen/largeText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_radius"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_refresh_map"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_refresh_map"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView_refresh_map"
            android:background="@color/radiusGrey"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ico_triangle_gris"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="15dip"
            android:paddingRight="15dip"
            android:text="@string/initial_radius"
            android:textColor="@color/radiusTextViewColor"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_refresh_map"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_title"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView_backToList"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:padding="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_refresh" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_backToList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_title"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:paddingBottom="8dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="9dip"
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_list_carte_red" />

    </RelativeLayout>



  <fragment
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/mapview_geolo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/geolocInfoContainer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is from Manifest file:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/mapsAPIv2" />
```

I have tested on API 10, 16, 22, 23. But in API 10 I have the inflate problem. I don't get what I have to change

Answer (score 0):

From the information you are sharing it doesn't appear that

> fragment_geoloc_map.xml

is in the view hierarchy.

You need to do one of the following:

- Include the fragment xml file in the activity layout
- Include the SupportMapFragment in the activity layout
- Provide the parent view you are inflating the fragment xml file into rather than null

If this does not make sense can you please post more code in your example (the activity code and layout file).

---

**Update**

You need to delegate the lifecycle events from the Activity/Fragment to the MapView.

You cannot call `getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)` until you have delegated:

- `onCreate(Bundle)`
- `onResume()`

You must then also delegate:

- `onPause()`
- `onDestroy()`
- `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`
- `onLowMemory()`

To the MapView in order to prevent memory leaks and allocation.